# D3.JS and Vue how to create a basic doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I have a Vue project where I try to draw a simple Doughnut chart. The chart I try to create is being displayed on the docs of D3.js: [Doughnut Chart](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/donut_basic.html).

But when I try to create this in Vue I cannot seem to get it to work. I keep on getting an
`[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: _ is not iterable"`.

Also is there a way to make the SVG fill the parent div so that it is responsive to the width and height of the parent.

```
<template>
  <div class="p-3 flex flex-col">
    <div class="w-full flex-1">
      <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default {
  name: "DoughnutChartItem",
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var width = 450;
    var height = 450;
    var margin = 40;

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

    // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
    var svg = d3
      .select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    // Create dummy data
    var data = { a: 9, b: 20, c: 30, d: 8, e: 12 };

    // set the color scale
    var color = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(data)
      .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);

    // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
    var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
    var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data));

    // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
    svg
      .selectAll("whatever")
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr(
        "d",
        d3
          .arc()
          .innerRadius(100) // This is the size of the donut hole
          .outerRadius(radius)
      )
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.data.key);
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("opacity", 0.7);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in the line `.domain(data)`:

```
// set the color scale
var color = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data) //<-- domain function is expecting an array not an object
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);
```

What you need there is:

```
// set the color scale
var color = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(Object.keys(data)) //<-- set domain to ['a','b','c','d','e']
  .range(['#98abc5', '#8a89a6', '#7b6888', '#6b486b', '#a05d56']);
```

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="p-3 flex flex-col" id="one">
      <div class="w-full flex-1">
        <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#one',
        data: {
          type: Array,
          required: true,
        },
        mounted() {
          // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
          var width = 450;
          var height = 450;
          var margin = 40;

          // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
          var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

          // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
          var svg = d3
            .select('#my_dataviz')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr(
              'transform',
              'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
            );

          // Create dummy data
          var data = { a: 9, b: 20, c: 30, d: 8, e: 12 };

          // set the color scale
          var color = d3
            .scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(Object.keys(data))
            .range(['#98abc5', '#8a89a6', '#7b6888', '#6b486b', '#a05d56']);

          // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
          var pie = d3.pie().value(function (d) {
            return d.value;
          });
          var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data));

          // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
          svg
            .selectAll('whatever')
            .data(data_ready)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr(
              'd',
              d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(100) // This is the size of the donut hole
                .outerRadius(radius)
            )
            .attr('fill', function (d) {
              return color(d.data.key);
            })
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .style('stroke-width', '2px')
            .style('opacity', 0.7);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**New snippet based on comments:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="p-3 flex flex-col" id="one">
      <div class="w-full flex-1">
        <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#one',
        data: {
          type: Array,
          required: true,
        },
        mounted() {
          // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
          var width = 450;
          var height = 450;
          var margin = 40;

          // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
          var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

          // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
          var svg = d3
            .select('#my_dataviz')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr(
              'transform',
              'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
            );

          // Create dummy data
          var data = { a: 9, b: 20, c: 30, d: 8, e: 12 };

          // set the color scale
          var color = d3
            .scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(Object.keys(data))
            .range(['#98abc5', '#8a89a6', '#7b6888', '#6b486b', '#a05d56']);

          // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
          var pie = d3.pie().value(function (d) {
            return d[1];
          });
                   
          var data_ready = pie(Object.entries(data));

          // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
          svg
            .selectAll('whatever')
            .data(data_ready)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr(
              'd',
              d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(100) // This is the size of the donut hole
                .outerRadius(radius)
            )
            .attr('fill', function (d) {
              return color(d.data[0]);
            })
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .style('stroke-width', '2px')
            .style('opacity', 0.7);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But If I change `.domain(data)` to `.domain(Object.keys(data))` I still get an error `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: d3__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.entries is not a function"`

Comment: You are using an old `d3` code sample with newer a `d3` library.  `d3.entries` is deprecated in version 6.  Note, my example is loading version 5.  I've added a new snippet that runs with v6.